# Aggregate Two Variables by One Date

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following dataset I am working with:

```
     day descent_cd
   <int> <chr>     
 1    26 B         
 2    19 W         
 3    19 B         
 4    16 B         
 5     1 W         
 6     2 W         
 7     2 B         
 8     2 B         
 9     3 W         
10     3 W         
# … with 1,283 more rows
```

In short: the "day" variable is the day of the month. "Descent_cd" is race (black or white).

I am trying to organize it so that I get a column for "B" and a column for "W" both sorted by total arrest made that day ... meaning: counting all the "B"s for day "1" and the same for "W" and then so on and so forth through the rest of the month.

I ultimately want to do this as a geom_ridge graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
#sample data
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~day, ~descent_cd,
    26L,      "B",
   19L,         "W",
   19L,         "B",
   16L,         "B",
    1L,         "W",
    2L,         "W",
    2L,         "B",
    2L,         "B",
    3L,         "W",
    3L,         "W"
  )

df %>% 
  group_by(day, descent_cd) %>% 
  summarise(total_arrest = n()) %>% #calculate number of arrests per day per descent_cd
  pivot_wider(names_from = descent_cd, values_from = total_arrest) %>% #create columns W and B
  mutate(W = if_else(is.na(W),as.integer(0),W), #replace NAs with 0 (meaning 0 arrests that day)
         B = if_else(is.na(B),as.integer(0),B)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(wt = W+B)) #arrange df in descending order of total arrests per day

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   day [6]
    day     W     B
  <int> <int> <int>
1     2     1     2
2     3     2     0
3    19     1     1
4     1     1     0
5    16     0     1
6    26     0     1
```

Comment: That worked perfectly to format it. Do you have any idea how to structure it for geom_density_ridges? Been playing with it since you helped me out with the first question and still cannot get it to happen.

Comment: Like this:? `df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = descent_cd)) +
  geom_density_ridges()` (but with the format of the `df` you posted.